# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_route$params.useremail')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i fix this error? when i am backing my screen than its showing me this error anyone knows how can i fix this problem? useremail and userVerificationCode i am getting from diffrent screen, you all can also see the function by which my useremail and userVerificationCode is coming from

```
const ForgetPassword_Verify = ({ navigation, route }) => {

  const { useremail, userVerificationCode } =  route.params
  
  console.log(useremail, userVerificationCode)

  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState('');


  const handleVerificationCode = () => {

    if (verificationCode != userVerificationCode) {
      alert('Invalid Verification Code')
    }
    else {
      alert('Verification Code Matched')
      navigation.navigate('forgetpassword_choose_newpassword', { email: useremail })
    }
  }
  return (
    <View style={containerFull}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('forgetpassword_email')} style={goback}>
        <AntDesign name="arrowleft" size={24} color="grey" />
        <Text style={{ color: 'grey', fontSize: 16, marginLeft: 5, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Go Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {/* <Image source={logo} style={logo1} /> */}
      <Text style={formHead3}>A verification code is sent to your email!</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder='Enter 6 digit code' placeholderTextColor="grey" style={formInput}
        onChangeText={(text) => setVerificationCode(text)}
      />

      <Text style={formbtn} onPress={() => handleVerificationCode()}>Next</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default ForgetPassword_Verify
```

useremail and userVerificationCode:

```
const handleEmail = () => {
        if (email === '') {
            alert('Please enter email')
        }

        else {
            setLoading(true)
            fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/verifyforgetpassword', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ email: email })
            })
                .then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                    if (data.error === "User not found with this email") {
                        alert('User not found with this email')
                        setLoading(false)
                    }
                    else if (data.message === "Verification Code Sent to your Email") {
                        setLoading(false)
                        alert(data.message);
                        navigation.navigate('forgetpassword_verify', {
                            useremail: data.email,
                            userVerificationCode: data.VerificationCode
                        })

                    }
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean by `backing my screen` is clicking back button? So there is no error if you navigated to the `forgetpassword_verify` screen without using the back button?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `react-router`? I also do not see where this `handleEmail` function is called. But guessing on what I see within the `react-router` you use the `useParams` to access the params. See: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params

Comment: Ah okay, then what happens if you try and navigate with `navigation.navigate('forgetpassword_verify, { params: { useremail: data.email, userVerificationCode: data.verificationCode } });` so add your currenty object passed to a key called `params`

Answer (score 0):

Because the data is received from the navigation parameter, if you navigate to that screen using the back button rather than `navigation.navigate`, the attribute `route.params` will be undefined because the back button does not send any parameters.

There are some possible solutions:

**Option 1**
Don't pass the data via navigation parameters; use global state instead. You can use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or a state management library such as Redux. Modify your data in global state on any screen, and read the data on another screen. This is the ideal solution, I think, because this issue can happen again on another screen if you still handle your data via the navigation parameter.

**Option 2**
Try to override your back button and pass parameters to navigation. Do this on any component screen that you want to go back to the `forgetpassword_verify` screen on back button pressed.

```js
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

useEffect(() => {
   const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => { 
      navigation.navigate('forgetpassword_verify', {
         useremail,
         userVerificationCode
      })
      return true;
   })

   return () => backHandler.remove()
}, [])
```

**Option 3**
Disable the back button with option `headerBackVisible: false​`, and implement your own back button UI.